# Update SQL Server table from Excel and then populating remaining column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-nt

SQLPLUS not available

I need to be able to call a SQL script from the command line and pass in parameters for use. The script will read in data from an excel spreadsheet (file specified also at command line) to append records to an existing table in the database.

There are two additional columns in the database table that do NOT exist in the spreadsheet. Those columns are month and year. Those two values need to be entered at the command line and populated for each new record added. Whatever is entered at the command line will be the same value for each of the new records. (Any existing records in the table need to be remain untouched).

Can you help?

I was thinking about using osql to specify the user, password, database and `.sql` file.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: SQL Server BI (64-bit)

Comment: Hi SbF, please post some code showing how you've attempted to tackle the problem, as this helps others help you.

Comment: Are you seriously running this on Windows NT? Why the tag?

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005**, `isql` and `osql` are **deprecated** and should not be used anymore. Use `sqlcmd` instead

Answer (score 0):

I do and would use powershell as described by
Not sure about formating link but paste into browser.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/getting-data-between-excel-and-sql-server-using-odbc/